# Как закрыть вызванное меню в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#but3").click(function(){ $("#square1").slideDown(500)});
   $("").click(function(){ $("#square1").slideUp(500)});
 

});
```

```css
#square
{
border:2px solid transparent;
padding:5px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
height:280px;
width:300px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
a{
 color:#d9d9d9;
 text-decoration:none;
}
li{
  display:block;
  width:140px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  background:#fff;
  border-bottom:2px solid #f3f3f3;
}
#square1{
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  left:102px;
  top:-30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="square">
  <nav>
   <ul>
     <li id="but3"><a href="#">Первая ссылка</a>
        <ul id="square1">
          <li><a href="#">Первая ссылка 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Первая ссылка 2</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Третья ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Четвёртая ссылка</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

в общем вызов по клику уже сделал а как его закрыть теперь это меню ?

Comment: А что говорят аналогичные программы? Чай, ваша-то не первая.

Comment: какие программы ?

Comment: Аналогичные. Или у вас не программа?

Comment: неее ! ручками пишу - я дае и не знаю таких программ особенно под Linux

Comment: NetBeans поставь, он кроссплатформенный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код - хлам, его надо переписать почти с нуля. Особенно JS.
Но можно так: заюзать дополнительный класс и получить это:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#but3").click(function(){ $("#square1").toggle('view');});
});
```

```css
#square
{
border:2px solid transparent;
padding:5px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
height:280px;
width:300px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
a{
 color:#d9d9d9;
 text-decoration:none;
}
li{
  display:block;
  width:140px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  background:#fff;
  border-bottom:2px solid #f3f3f3;
}
#square1{
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  left:102px;
  top:-30px;
  display:none;
}
.view{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="square">
  <nav>
   <ul>
     <li id="but3"><a href="#">Первая ссылка</a>
        <ul id="square1">
          <li><a href="#">Первая ссылка 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Первая ссылка 2</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Третья ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Четвёртая ссылка</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо ! но всё таки мне интересно - что в коде какашного ? особенно меня интересует html , вы сказали что он какашка

Comment: Я не сказал что код - дарьмо, всего лишь хлам.
В основном про JS, там второй запуск jQuery с пустым селектором ушёл.
А в HTML - в `nav` следует заворачивать, а не наоборот. И, главное, в ссылках не используй `id`, грех это! Точнее говнокод (да, тут дарьмо :)), навигацию придётся для каждого элемента писать, надо классы использовать.

Comment: ты мог бы меня подучить ? не часто -  желательно через  skype

Comment: Нет, спасибо. Хотя за кругленькую сумму, возможно, я бы передумал.

Comment: Фланаган поучит - всё равно спасибо